# Integrating QML and a Map/Location Technology for Windows

Tags: c++, qt, geolocation, qml

I need to display a map containing markers for some devices locations. This application runs on windows (Desktop).

I am trying to find a good technology to display the map, and use coordinates, but I am having no success on finding any.

I've read a bit about QT Location Module and its Map component which seems to be really easy to use, but I couldn't make it work on windows (Compile doesn't find the module). People said this module is for mobile only.

My question is: is there a good api for using map/location with QT, QML into a Desktop application??

Comment: Did you download this module?

Comment: I downloaded the QT 5.3 release. Doesn't it come with it?

Comment: It doesn't. Look at @BaCaRoZzzo's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location is going to be integrated in the main release of Qt but it is currently just an [Add-on Module](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Add-ons-Modules) (`git` download url on the fourth row). 
Useful information to ease the installation can be found in this [thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/26175) of the Qt forum.

Finally, I've investigated the problem myself sometime ago and I've found this [site](http://www.ics.com/technologies/qt-based-clients-google-apis#.VE5PhON5Prh) full of interesting projects which uses *Google API*. Each project can be downloaded from GoogleCode. I've **not test** any of them but they look quite promising and **maybe** they can satisfy your needs.